# CSS white-space long text not wrapping to next line

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have the following structure rendered dynamically in DOM

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <label>WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

For the above case (long text with all W's), I want to wrap the text to the next line (or even truncating text with ellipsis is fine if that can be done via CSS)

I have already tried all the values for white-space (tried applying to all the 3 DOM elements), but it is not wrapping. Is there some other property I need to check which might be preventing text from wrapping to next line?

Just to add, I have this structure within a flex container.

Comment: Tried that as well...giving width and word-wrap: break-word;....but even that does not work

Answer (score 4):

You need `word-break: break-word;` or  `overflow-wrap: break-word;` on the `label` element. But please consider that your example is completely unrealistic – real sentences / phrases contain spaces, and real words are hardly ever that long.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}

label {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <label>WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `word-break` style to it.

```css
label {
  word-break: break-word
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <label>WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried...but for some strange reason, it does not work !